# I want to find JSON objects that meet the conditions and gather them

Tags: javascript, json, dom

I'm learning Javascipt, and I want to find JSON objects that meet the conditions and gather them.
*Condition: @type = "Product"
I used this code to parse JSON that meets the condition.

```
var jsonArray = [];
var jsons = document.querySelectorAll('script[type="application/ld+json"]');
for(var i=0; i<jsons.length; i++){
var parsingJSON = JSON.parse(jsons[i].innerText);
var product =  parsingJSON.filter(function(json) {
    return json['@type'] == 'Product';
});
jsonArray.push(product);
};
```

The problem is that each site has a different JSON form. Some are in the form of arrays,

```
<script type="application/ld+json">[{"@context":"https://schema.org","@type":"Product","name":...}, {"@context":"https://schema.org","@type":"BreadCrumb","name":...},...]
```

the others are single objects,

```
<script type="application/ld+json">{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"BreadcrumbList","itemListElement":...}
</script>
(In this case filter function is not working.)
```

How can I find JSON objects that meet the conditions and gather them when JSON form is different? 
I need your help. Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, You are receiving two types,

**Array of Objects**

```
[{"@context":"https://schema.org","@type":"Product","name":...},{"@context":"https://schema.org","@type":"BreadCrumb","name":...},...]
```

**Object**

```
{"@context":"http://schema.org","@type":"BreadcrumbList","itemListElement":...}
```

The method `filter` is only applicable to `Array`. You **can't** use it for an object. That's why you are getting the error...

So before apply `filter`, You need to check, whether the data is `array` or `object`.

```js
var jsonArray = [];
var jsons = document.querySelectorAll('script[type="application/ld+json"]');
for(var i=0; i<jsons.length; i++){
    var parsingJSON = JSON.parse(jsons[i].innerText);
    
    if(Array.isArray(parsingJSON)) {
      var product =  parsingJSON.filter(function(json) {
        return json['@type'] === 'Product';
      });
    } else {
      var product = (parsingJSON['@type'] === 'Product') ? parsingJSON : null;
    }
    
    if (product !== null) {
     jsonArray.push(product);
    }

};
```

Answer (score 1):

At some point you'll need to determine whether the JSON that you parsed is an array of objects or a single object, and then choose how to process it. Try [`Array.isArray()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray)

Comment: Thanks for your tips! I'll try it :)